# 3D: What to hardcode and what not

Tags: java, 3d, hardcode

I just wonder what do I hardcode in my game? E.g do I have an external file for every `Enemy` properties so on or do I make a class?

So what info/stuff should I code and what should I have as a .file?

Cheers!

Comment: this question is too localized.

Comment: You're pretty much asking us how to code your application. The only one that will benefit from an answer is you.

Comment: Not my application. A 3D game in general, how the best approach to handle information.

Comment: How is this related to java, 3D or pygame? This is sounds like a question regarding hardcoding practices in general.

Comment: oops, I somehow choosed pygame :O sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a properties file, and instantiate a bean when you need that type of property.  There aren't many good reasons to hardcode things.  At the very least, make the hardcoded items into constants: `public static final int XYZZY = 0;`

That being said, I'll hardcode to get something working or for prototyping. Then I'll go back and generalize it.

Comment: So I should use files instead of classes to store Info?

Comment: It's hard to say definitively without seeing an example or knowing more about your app.  If there were 100 different types of Enemy, probably.  If there are 3, maybe not.  In the ideal world you'd be able to create one class whose behavior changes based upon the properties file.  At this point you get into more interesting implementations.

Comment: Well ye alot of diffrent "enemies" and weapons. So I consider making my game import those files.

thanks!